# Dynamically Load Google Map AJAX Tutorial

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am sure there is a tutorial somewhere on the net on how to dynamically load markers to Google Maps while Zooming In and Out through AJAX.

Some like this site is doing http://www.visualtour.com/p_findahome.asp?q=toronro+ontario

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#geoxml_rss

You can create a XML file. And you can get clicked position and write it to your xml file. You drag markers from xml file while loading map.

http://code.google.com/intl/tr/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html